# import error when running django south

Tags: django, django-south

I added a ManyToMany field between my facebook user and car Reviews to ./facebook/model.py  which required me to insert:

```
from car.models import Review
```

I try to run:

```
./manage.py schemamigration facebook --auto
```

but i get error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: ImportError haystack: cannot import name Review
```

The problem is, my facebook app has nothing to do with the third party haystack module.  I tried some simple debugging and found as long as i try to import Review, i get the error.  It doesn't matter if I change the model or not. Could it be the order of my "INSTALLED_APPS"?  I have "car" followed by "facebook" and then "haystack".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, a bit of background on how imports work: When you run a statement like "`from x.y import z`", the entire module `x.y` is executed, and then the interpreter pulls `z` and places it in your namespace.

So, your underlying problem probably has nothing to do with South or Haystack; it's probably in `car.models` somewhere. That's why you're getting an error no matter how you come across the importing of `Review`, and you'll likely get it if you try to import anything else from that module.

Check `car.models` for problems -- in particular, you might have a circular import (in other words, a case where A imports from B *and* B imports from A).

Answer (score 1):

Or simply the model with its files does not exist in your environment but does exist in your configuration :)
 (happened to me when I forgot to "git add" a folder and after building into staging got this error...)